# Pyspark SQL : Converting a string to timestamp custom format

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert a input of string datatype (which is MMYYYY format - has only month & year) to a custom format in timestamp.

In the output the input string should be converted into timestamp having 00 hours, 00 minutes, 00 seconds and 000 milliseconds and '01' should be concatenated as the date.

For example : Input string is : "102003" then the Output should be : 2003-10-01 00:00:00.000 (in timestamp format)

This is what I have tried so far :

```py
date_format(to_timestamp('01' || COL_1), 'DDMMYYYY')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
select date_format(to_timestamp('072022','MMyyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

replace the 072022 with your column

Comment: Thank you Anjaneya! It worked perfectly. Just curious, how would it be different if it were a date other than 01 ?

Comment: if 05072022 is passed it will fail as the format of input will not be same as format defined in to_timestamp also please upvote/accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: How would we make it work for 05072022 then?

Comment: in pyspark we can do by checking length in when and if length is 8 then use ddMMyyyy in format and when length is 6 then use MMyyyy in format while casting to timestamp

Comment: Thank you! I tried to upvote your answer but not able to do so due to some reason.